# I have multiple dataframe and how to stop the process if one dataframe is empty

Tags: python-3.x

How to stop the process if one of the df is empty before loading to database.

```
def dataframe_check(df):
    name =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
    if df.empty == True:
        print(name + ' Dataframe is empty!')
    return name + ' Dataframe is not empty!'
    
print(dataframe_check(on_air_data_read))
print('')
print(dataframe_check(vlr_data_read))
print('')
print(dataframe_check(warroom_outage))
print('')
print(dataframe_check(south_2g))
print('')
print(dataframe_check(south_3g))
print('')
print(dataframe_check(south_4g))
print('')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exit(1)` or `sys.exit(1)` to stop the python process in the dataframe_check function if this is the main thread. Any non zero exit code is considered error, you can use any value in the arg of the exit call.

```py
def dataframe_check(df):
    name =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
    if df.empty == True:
        print(name + ' Dataframe is empty!')
        exit(1)
    return name + ' Dataframe is not empty!'
```

Link to sys.exit doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit for details on how it causes program exit.